# Single sign-on - implementation for 3 domains

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

My company has 3 applications on 3 different domains. Next thing we would like to do is to implement a single sign-on solution, so when a user is already authenticated in one app, they don't need to authenticate again in the others.

I know about **OAuth2**, but I don't feel confident when it comes to fully grasping its idea. Additionally, I got the impression that **OAuth2 would be an overkill in our case**, because the 3 application are all ours, so they're not really "third parties" to each other - they're trusted and they're all developed by us. **We also don't really need a full API approach**, which would be passing an `access_token` with every request that requires auth-access.

I see the process simply:

1. User comes in. First, check if they are already authenticated on one of the 3 domains.
2. If the user **is not** authenticated yet, redirect them to login
   page and employ the successful login attempt to "mark" the user as
   authenticated across all 3 platforms.
3. If the user **is** already authenticated on one of the 3 platforms,
   simply provide the requested resource without the need to log in.

I could put a big "HOW?" after the first two points, so... **How would we go about it to achieve just what we need?**

I've been looking for examples online. Most of them deal with **the one scenario** of first page visit, in which the user is asked to log in, so the application can get an `access_token` to communicate on behalf of the user. That's cool, but I'm really interested in is the case that comes later, when the same user visits another affiliated domain.

I understand this is a theoretical "how-to" problem, but still I would be very grateful for any suggestions or resources that could shed some light on the kind of implementation we could (or should) use.

Comment: login gateway for 3 domains ^.^ just a fast idea

Comment: Aaandd, doesn't it mean that the user needs to log in separately for each domain (which we don't want)?

Comment: I came across https://github.com/jasny/sso#readme , try it

Comment: Yep, this is one solution we're considering. I just want to get as many possibilities as I can :) Thx.

Answer (score 1):

We started using [Central Authentication Service](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/index.html) at my company to great success. See [this](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/gh-pages/development/protocol/CAS-Protocol.md) for a great sequence diagram for SSO in CAS. CAS supports several protocols OOTB including SAML and OAuth2, and also supports several user databases OOTB. We're using LDAP to store and authenticate users.

To answer your question, after login with the SSO provider, your client gets a cookie with a "ticket-granting ticket" (TGT). When they try to access any secure resource, they're redirected to the login page again, but if they already have that TGT, the SSO provider immediately redirects back to the secure resource with a "service ticket" (ST) in a query parameter. The ST is used by the server to validate that the user is authenticated with CAS, and it can even get attributes about the user (things like roles, name, phone number, etc.). The server then should start a session with the client so that that redirect handshake only happens the first time the client tries to access the secure resource.

CAS has a [PHP client](https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS).

Comment: Looks very nice, great diagram indeed. Will check it out for sure. Thank you!